# Prove that a non-empty subset of an open set which is evenly covered is evenly covered

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Let $p: E\rightarrow B$ a continuous surjective map and $U \subseteq B$ be open and not empty and who is being evenly covered by $p$. Show that all non-empty subsets of $U$ are being evenly covered by $p$.

**What I've got so far with the hints:**

Let $W \subseteq U$ with $W$ open and non-empty.

$$
W = W \cap U = W \cap p( \cup V_\alpha)
$$

So that
$$
p^{-1}(W) = p^{-1}(W \cap p(\cup V_\alpha)) = p^{-1}(W) \cap \cup V_\alpha = \cup (p^{-1}(W) \cap V_\alpha)
$$

Since $p$ is continuous and $W$ is open in $B$ we know $p^{-1}(W)$ is open and $V_\alpha$ is open by definition. So $p^{-1}(W) \cap V_\alpha$ is open.

Next up we have to prove that:

$$
p: p^{-1}(W) \cap V_\alpha \rightarrow W
$$
is a homeomorphism. By definition $p$ is continuous and surjective and notice that only $p(0) = 0$ so this map is also injective.
If $Z \subseteq W \subseteq U$ with $Z$ open then we know

$$
p(p^{-1}(Z) \cap V_\alpha) = Z \cap V_\alpha 
$$
is open. So $p$ is also an open mapping and thus is $p$ a homeomorphism and thus is $W \subseteq U$ being evenly covered by $p$.

Comment: Define "evenly covered." I'm not sure that is a normal phrase.

Comment: Let $p : E \rightarrow B$ be a continuous surjective map. The open set $U$ of $B$ is said to be evenly covered by $p$ if the inverse image $p^{-1}(U)$ can be written as the union of disjoint open sets $V_\alpha$ in $E$ such that for each $\alpha$, the restriction of $p$ to $V_\alpha$ is a homeomoprshim of $V_\alpha$ onto $U$. From Munkres second edition page 336.

Comment: Ok,that's a rather unusual terminology in topology,but point set topology is loaded with such "specialized" terminology. It's one of the things that annoys non-specialists about it.Your reasoning looks fine so far,but you haven't achieved homeomorphism yet.You have to prove the restriction of p is one to one and open i.e. $p^{-1}$ is  continuous from B onto E. .

Comment: While not universal, the term is also used in Spanier's Algebraic Topology and Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds (among others). @Nescrio Did you try just restricting $U$'s cover to $W \subset U$? If $V_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to $U$ via $p$, then $V_\alpha \cap p^{-1}(W)$ is homeomorphic to $W$ via $p$.

Comment: @AymanHourieh I'm not sure what you mean by $ \cup V_\alpha \cap p^{-1}(W)$ is homeorphic to $W$. We indeed know that $p( \cup V_\alpha) = U$.

Comment: Careful, it's $V_\alpha \cap p^{-1}(W)$ that is homeomorphic to $W$, not $\bigcup V_\alpha \cap p^{-1}(W)$. Stefan's answer below elaborates on this idea.

Comment: A, yes, "evenly covered" is used as an interim definition on the way to defining "covering map." It is, to a normal definition as "Lemma" is to "Proof." After you've defined "covering map," you never use "evenly covered" again. :)

Comment: @AymanHourieh I updated my proof. Could you check if it is now correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $W\subseteq U$, you have $p^{-1}(W)=p^{-1}(W)\cap\coprod_\alpha V_\alpha$ which is the union $\coprod_\alpha p^{-1}(W)\cap V_\alpha$. Can you show that each $p^{-1}(W)\cap V_\alpha$ is open and that $p:p^{-1}(W)\cap V_\alpha\to W$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: What does $\coprod_\alpha$ mean? I haven't seen this notation before.

Comment: $\coprod$ means "disjoint union", you could as well use $\bigsqcup$, it has the same meaning, just different style. Of course you could just use $\bigcup$, but the other symbol emphasizes that the sets are disjoint.

Comment: @Nescrio: In the context of topology, $X=\coprod_\alpha X_\alpha$ may also indicate that all $X_\alpha$ are open (in $X$), so that $X$ is the *topological sum* of the spaces $X_\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for the information! :-) I'm working on it right now, I'll get back at you in a few minutes.

Comment: I'm not sure how to show it is a homeomorphism.. I updated my question btw.

Comment: I updated my proof. Could you check it?

Comment: @Nescrio: I don' know what you mean by $p(0)=0$, you have an arbitrary space and not a group. Note that when $p:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, and $A\subset X$, then $p:A\to p(A)$ is also a homeomorphism. This means that $p:p^{-1}(W)\cap V_\alpha\to p(p^{-1}(W)\cap V_\alpha)$ is a homeomorphism. It only remains to check that $p(p^{-1}(W)\cap V_\alpha)=W$.